# Get distinct data of SharePoint list using REST API

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How to get distinct column data of SharePoint list using REST API?
Is there a way to achieve it without looping?

Thanks!

Comment: Better do some research before asking, since this is not a tutorial site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx), such operation as `grouping`  is not supported.

The solution, is to apply grouping **after** the JSON results are returned from SharePoint REST service.

### How to get distinct values from an array using jQuery

```
function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}


var catalog = { products: [
   { category: "Food & Dining"},
   { category: "Techonology"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"}
]};

var categoryNames = groupBy(catalog.products, 'category'); //get distinct categories
console.log(categoryNames);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/auB6B/5/)

### Example

Suppose the following function is used for getting list items via SharePoint REST API:

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then the following example demonstrates how to print distinct task names:

```
getListItems('https://tenant.sharepoint.com/project','Tasks','?select=Title',
    function(items){    
       var taskNames = groupBy(items,'Title');
       console.log(taskNames);
    },
    function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

Comment: This will *not* work, if you have more than 100 results.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand that you are talking about http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx.

Well Yes, you should be able to query the data through simple SQL - select Distinct...

I have been using the same concept for Users web service. However, it is just a lead for you.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms429658(v=office.14).aspx